# Checkbox in JTable always return false despite of it's checked

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, jtable

I am using checkboxes in `JTable` which itsef is part of `JPanel`. Initially I was using `JOptionPane` and on clicking OK button I was getting value but now I added `JPanel` in a `JFrame`. When I click `X` sign on top right it is not retrieving value of clicked Checkboxes but able to fetch values of other columns. Code snippet given below:

```
DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(rowData, columnNames)
        {
        };
for (int i = 0; i < records.size(); i++)
            {
               // System.out.println(records.get(i));
                singleRecord = records.get(i).toString().split("%");
                Pages = singleRecord[0].toString();
                BKey= singleRecord[1].toString();
                Title = singleRecord[2].toString();
                Author = singleRecord[3].toString();
                TimeStamp = singleRecord[4].toString();
                dtm.addRow(new Object[] { Boolean.FALSE ,Pages,BKey,Title,Author,TimeStamp});

        } 

table = new javax.swing.JTable(dtm)
        {
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row,int column)
            {
                /*if(column == 0)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
                 * 
                 */
                return(column < 2);
            }
        };

for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++)
            {
                 System.out.println(table.getValueAt(i,1).toString());
                 boolean isChecked = (Boolean) table.getValueAt(i,0);//always return false
                 if (isChecked)
                 {
                     System.out.println("checked ");
                   Ids+=table.getValueAt(i,2).toString()+"%";
                 }
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Follow Java variable naming standards. Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Some of you names are correct. Others are not. Be consistent!!!
2. If you are always getting false then it is probably because the editor is not updating the value to Boolean.TRUE when you click on the cell. Not only do you need to override the `isCellEditable(...)` method to determine which cells are editable, you would need to override the `getColumnClass(...)` method to return the class of the cell (in this this case `Boolean.class`) so the table can use the appropriate renderer and editor.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out naming conventions issue. Speaking of problem, the code was working fine. I just moved `JPanel` in `JFrame` and it stopped fetching value. It sounds illogical but it's happening.

Comment: @volatil3 Then you need to supply a runnable example which demonstrates your problem

Comment: @MadProgrammer I just updated the question. The code is part of OpenOffice plugin so not sure how do I give entire code. I am using `DefaultTableModel`